# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'

Tags: java, android, lombok

```
android 
{

compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig 

{

applicationId "downloader.video.full.videodownloader"

minSdkVersion 15

targetSdkVersion 27

versionCode 1

versionName "1.1"

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes 

{


release 

{

minifyEnabled false

proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-
rules.pro'

}

}

}

dependencies 

{

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.io.tools.android.ramiloif.folderchooser:folderchooser-
dialog:1.0.6'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

implementation files('libs/json-20140107.jar')

implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.1'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'

}
```

I get this error when I build my code:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
    - lombok-1.16.14.jar (org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.14)
  Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
  See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.
```

This is my project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's best to keep questions as concise and readable as possible, so take your time to correctly indent the source code to be properly displayed. Also, you might want to post what attempts you made to solve your problem to, this helps readers jumping right into your questions.

Comment: You expect others to spend their time to solve your problem. So you please spend the 5 minutes required to come up with well formatted input. That preview window, and all the explanations how to format your input exist for a reason...

Answer (score 1):

```
It tells you what to do...

> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  

> Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.  
      - lombok-1.16.14.jar (org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.14)

Like so

    dependencies {

        // Other dependencies
        compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4"
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    }

[See Lombok documentation](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android)

Also, I suggest you delete `libs/json-20140107.jar` and replace it with 

    compile 'org.json:json:20140107'

Although, Android already has a JSON parser, so not clear why you need this at all
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add Following Lines into your Module:app gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4"
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
 }
```